# How do I load rows into dataTable 2 when a row in dataTable 1 is clicked?

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have a form with a panel and two dataTables.  The code below has had most of the columns removed to make it easier to follow.

```
<h:form id="invoiceLookUp"> 
<p:panel>                 
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">
                        Invoice Selection Criteria
                    </p:column>                    
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="Seq ID"/>
            <p:inputText
                id="invoice_header_seq_id" styleClass="field" size="10"
                value="#{invoiceBean.invoice_header_seq_id}"
            />
            <p:commandButton
                update="invoicesTable" value="Look Up"
                action="#{invoiceBean.addInvoices()}"
            />                
</p:panel>
<p:dataTable
    id="invoicesTable" var="invoice" rows="15" lazy="true" selectionMode="single" 
    value="#{invoiceBean.invoiceList}"
    rowKey="#{invoice.invoiceHeader.invoiceHeaderSeqId}"                
    selection="#{invoiceBean.selectedInvoice}"
>
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":invoiceLookUp:invoiceLinesTable"/>
    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Invoice Headers" /></f:facet>
    <p:column sortBy="#{invoice.invoiceHeader.invoiceHeaderSeqId}" id="invoiceSeqId">
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Seq ID" title="Invoice Header Seq ID"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{invoice.invoiceHeader.invoiceHeaderSeqId}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable> 
<p:dataTable
    id="invoiceLinesTable" var="invoiceLine" rows="15" lazy="true" selectionMode="single"
    value="#{invoiceBean.selectedInvoice.invoiceLines}"
    rowKey="#{invoiceLine.invoiceLineSeqId}"                
    selection="#{invoiceBean.selectedInvoiceLine}"
        >
    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Invoice Lines" /></f:facet>
    <p:column sortBy="#{invoiceLine.invoiceLineSeqId}" id="invoiceLineSeqId">  
        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Line Seq ID"/></f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{invoiceLine.invoiceLineSeqId}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

When you enter a Seq ID and then click Look Up, the table populates as expected.  When I select a row in the invoicesTable, I get the following error:
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":invoiceLookUp:invoiceLinesTable" referenced from "form:invoiceLookUp:invoicesTable".

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: They're already in the same form try to delete :invoiceLookUp: in the ajax update i can't test your code right now.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı - following your advice, I get this error:  javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "invoiceLinesTable" referenced from "form:j_idt19:invoicesTable".

Comment: Well, I figured it out by searching StackOverflow for an hour: <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":#{p:component('invoiceLinesTable')}"/> the solution looks like a work around for a bug in my opinion, but it works, so that's all that really matters.

Comment: I was about to post this solution: update="@([id$=invoiceLinesTable])" maybe it works. I don't think it's a bug. You can give the correct id without an EL expression. Right click on the browser click view source and try to find correct id of dataTable in generated html.